# iohook builds for electron or node: Cannot find module node_modules\iohook\builds\electron-v87-win32-x64\build\Release\iohook.node

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am using node 14.21.3 (ABI=83) and electron 12.2.3 (ABI=87) to quick start my electron app on windows x64.
Now I want to install iohook in my project: `npm install iohook --save`
It only generates node-v83-win32-x64/ in node_modules/iohook/builds/ directory, instead of electron-v87-win32-x64/, and after `npm run` it throw error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\projects\electron-quick-start-main\node_modules\iohook\builds\electron-v87-win32-x64\build\Release\iohook.node'
```

It seems the project needs builds for electron, not for node. I went to https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ to download the electron prebuilt files and it worked.

My question is: why it only built for node instead of for electron? How can I make it build for electron using simple install command? Because I want others to install my project quickly.